# Why is esp8266 client not connected to server?

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am new to Arduino and I am not so familiar with it. I am not sure why the client cannot connect to the server and I have been looking at it for hours. Any solution to this would be a great help.

So I successfully establish a server with the code below. But...

```
// server.ino
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "WifiName"; // Wifie name
const char* password = "WifiPassword"; // Wifi password
float sensor_value = 0.0;
String Website;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print("."); 
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("Server started at port 80."); 
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.print("URL=http://");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.on("/", handleIndex); //use the top root path report last sensor value
  server.on("/update",handleUpdate); // use this route to update sensor value
  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  server.handleClient();
}

void handleIndex(){ 
    Website = "<html><body onload ='process()'><div id='div1'>"+ String(sensor_value) +"</div></body></html>";
    server.send(200," text/html",Website);
}

void handleUpdate(){
  sensor_value = server.arg("value").toFloat();
  Serial.println(sensor_value);
  server.send(200,"text/plain","Updated");
}
```

I try to connect a client to the server so it could send data to the server, but a connection between the client and the server cannot be established and I don't know why. I check the IP address and it is all correct I just don't get why the client fails to connect to the server

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <HX711.h>
#include "Wire.h"

#define DOUT D5
#define CLK D6
HX711 scale;

const char* ssid     = "WifiName";
const char* password = "Wifipassowrd";
float calibration_factor = 107095; 
float val_Weight;

const char* host = "192.168.0.167"; // Server host IP.
const int port = 80;
WiFiClient client;


void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);       //set baud rate
   Serial.println("Connecting to ");
   Serial.println(ssid); 

   WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
        {
          delay(500);//millisecond
          Serial.print(".");
          }
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("WiFi connected & connect to client"); 
  
}

void loop() {

  //connect to the server and send the data as URL parameter

  if(client.connect(host, port)){
    String url = "update?value=";
    url+=String(25.0);
    client.print(String("GET /") + url + "HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    delay(10);

    Serial.println("Response: ");
    while(client.available()){
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
      Serial.print(line);
    }
  }else{
    Serial.println("fail");
  }

   
}
```

Any help would be great thanks!!!

Comment: What is `Connection: ckise`?

Comment: @hcheung oops sorry it supposes to be "connection: close"

Comment: I would test first if the http server is accessible from other clients, for example in a web browser on PC. I suppose all are in the same local WiFi network. Do you allocate a static IP to the ESP server at 192.168.0.167? If not then DHCP can give it some other IP address.
The same you can check if the ESP client works OK with http server on PC.

Comment: As @out_of_road mentioned above, the passwords in client and server code are not the same

Answer (score 0):

Check the passwords, you have a typo.

```
const char* password = "Wifipassowrd";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).